# Why does building error in idea maven project window whereas building success through same command in idea terminal

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, clojure

I would like to build storm-starter in storm-1.1.1 . To do that I use intellij ic 2017.2 ,click the storm-starter/lifecycle/package in "maven project" window.actually the ide execute the command:

```
/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/home/wxh/opensource/storm/examples/storm-starter -DarchetypeCatalog=internal -Dmaven.home=/opt/maven3.5.0 -Dclassworlds.conf=/opt/maven3.5.0/bin/m2.conf -javaagent:/opt/ideaic171/lib/idea_rt.jar=45019:/opt/ideaic171/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /opt/maven3.5.0/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2017.2.5 --errors -s /home/wxh/.m2/settings.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=/home/wxh/repo/mvnrepo -DskipTests=true clean package -P intellij
```

after a wile,we can see under exception messages:
[image: Exception call stacktraces]

But if I copy the same command to the idea terminal and execute the command, the build progress is successful.

What can I do for the problem?